# How can we set up (and administer) an EAP-Like program for financial crises?

Tags: benefits

I work for a medium-size company, with around 85 employees. An employee of ours has a daughter with a brain tumor, and had surgery yesterday. The company is pretty tight-knit, and we raised some money to pay for meals and sundries pretty quickly.

This got me thinking about a structured and legal way to provide for these kinds of emergencies. I looked into an EAP, but that doesn't really seem to cover this kind of thing - EAPs appear to be more oriented towards personal rather than medical crises.

Furthermore, if it were possible, I would like something more akin to the old Mutual Aid Societies, wherein we could conceivably provide assistance to pay a huge deductible / medical bill. I'm sure that's not covered by an EAP.

Let me forestall the first answer everyone is going to rush to say - better benefits. That's great, and we may well negotiate that, but I want to create an option that we can all contribute to voluntarily and not have it subject to management (unless we choose them to administer it).

Lots of legal issues here, I'm sure. Anyone out there have experience with this?

Comment: Nope. Just a high-level employee.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time I have only seen things like this handled on a case by case basis and raise money right away for an immediate crisis. At one company, it was suggested to set up something like this and the HR VP was enthusiastic about the idea but once they looked into the mechanics of how it would work, it was determined to not be a viable idea. At a minimum you will need legal assistance to make sure it is done correctly, a way to set up a payroll deduction, a way to determine who qualifies for the need and how they apply and a way to make sure the funds are kept separate and used only for the intended purpose and were auditable.

One thing I have seen companies set up successfully was a leave bank, where people could contribute some of their leave to people who were in crisis. Usually there is an option to contribute to a specific person or to a general fund that people would have to apply to get leave from. Don't negate this as a way to help those in a medical crisis, it is really easy to use up all your leave with a child who has cancer.

Another thing that works in today's world is for the person to set up a gofundme page and then have the company share that URL with the employees. This gets the company out of the need to administer the program and might be a much easier sell.

Alternatively, you and a group of co-workers could set up your own charity (consult a lawyer, there are legal hoops to go through) and ask you company to allow people to contribute to the charity through payroll deductions. This is more of a traditional mutual aid society. You could set it up so that only current and former employees of Company ABC can join the the society and get benefits from it. You then have the work of appointing a board and administering the funds and creating the rules for eligibility and determining who to give money to and how much and where to invest the money in the meantime.